SSRS and Imbedded JavaScript
I have a SSRS report Embed on a Browser’s Page. On this report i have an image. When I got Image properties on this image I select
Actions , Go to URL and have the following
JavaScript=
javascript:void(window.open('https://p21.castertech.com/Prophet21/index.html#/window/m_customermasterinquiry?customer_id=" & parameters!CustID.value & "','_blank'))

When I go the command line of the Browser and fill in custid with a value such as=
javascript:void(window.open('https://p21.castertech.com/Prophet21/index.html#/window/m_customermasterinquiry?customer_id=50','_blank'))

for testing it works.
When I click on the image on the Report with the same date nothing happens. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Browser is chrome, JavaScript is on, SSRS Current Version 15
One other note I have scripts on textbox properties again go to statements
javascript:void(window.open('https://p21.castertech.com/Prophet21/index.html#/window/m_orderentry?order_no=" & Fields!order_number.Value & "','_blank'))

that are not working also.

It looks like the JavaScript isn't enclosed in quotes to create the string.
="javascript:void(window.open('https://p21.castertech.com/Prophet21/index.html#/window/m_customermasterinquiry?customer_id=" & parameters!CustID.value & "','_blank'))"
